# Find $z$ such that $|z+3-i√3|=√3$ and $z$ have the smallest argument

Tags: complex-numbers

I let $z$ equal to $(-3)$ so $|-i√3|=√3$ which is true but I don't know how to explain it or maybe this is not right at all. I mean maybe there is another solution that have the argument smaller than $z=-3$. Please help me

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by "argument"? Because, in my book, $\operatorname{Arg}(-3)=\pi$, and it is hardly ever the least possible argument of anything.

Comment: @Gae.S. the argument is the smallest of all and positive

Comment: Positive as in $[0,2\pi)$ (i.e. non-negative), or as in $(0,2\pi]$?

Comment: @Gae.S. hmm...I don't know what I should say but the question only say the smallest and positive :(

Comment: Argument means the [complex argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_argument). You have a circle with radius $\sqrt 3$ centered at $-3 + i \sqrt 3$ and a ray that rotates around the origin, and you need to choose the ray that has the smallest angle with the positive real axis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = x+iy$. Then, $$|z+3-i\sqrt{3}| = |(x+3)+i(y-\sqrt{3})| = \sqrt{(x+3)^2+(y-\sqrt{3})^2}$$

Now, setting this equal to $\sqrt{3}$ and squaring both sides: $$(x+3)^2+(y-\sqrt{3})^2=3$$

This is the equation of a circle, centre $(-3, \sqrt{3})$ and radius $\sqrt{3}$.

The question then becomes: Which point on this circle has the smallest argument?

Comment: I was doing the same thing and I also derivate it too but I don't know if I'm wrong or right at all

Comment: @user635988 Draw the circle and determine the minimum modulus of $z$. Under what conditions will this occur? What is the shortest distance between two points?

Comment: hi did you mean by taking the shortest distance between the circle and the point $(0,0)$?

Comment: @user635988 Perhaps look at the line that passes through $(-3, \sqrt{3})$ and $(0,0)$. Where does this intersect the circle? Is this the shortest distance from the origin to the circle? Does that mean that $z$ here has the minimum modulus?